How to automatically run one CS file on Visual Studio Code using "CMD + B"?
I have a folder called z-lib structured as:
z-lib
   cpp
   java
   python
   csharp
         a.cs
         ...

I want to automatically run a.cs file using CMD + B keyboard combination on Visual Studio Code (macbook).
Tried
In my settings.json, I have so far this "set up":
"csharp": "dotnet build $dir$fileName && dotnet run $dir$fileName",


It returns:
MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
/Users/Username/Downloads/z-lib/csharp/a.cs(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Build FAILED.

/Users/Username/Downloads/z-lib/csharp/a.cs(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04

have also tried:
    // "csharp": "cd $dir && dotnet run --project $dir$fileName",
    // "csharp": "cd $dir && dotnet build $fileName && dotnet run $fileName",
    // "csharp": "dotnet build $fileName && dotnet run $fileNameWithoutExt",

which dotnet command
/usr/local/bin/dotnet
a.cs
using System;

public class b {
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}

How do I automatically run a ".cs" file using CMD + B on VS Code?

This question is not relevant to C#. But I'm tagging, so that someone with C# experience answer it.
